# Retrieve data from InputStream

Tags: ios, swift, sockets, swift3, xcode9

I have an app that pulls data from a socket using the Stream class.

Everything appears to work as expected, I am receiving data in the delegate method:

`func stream(_ Stream: Stream, handle eventCode: Stream.Event)`

The challenge I am having is converting the data into useful information. There is an Android app that does what I am trying to accomplish using a `ByteBuffer`.

This `ByteBuffer` iterates through the data at intervals of 4 and parses the data into the required data types using methods like `getFloat` and `getInt`.

Basically I want to loop through the InputStream data and retrieve all the values in the stream. Each value is always 4 bytes in length.

How can I do this using Swift 3?

Answer (score 2):

I got it working. If anyone else needs to do something similar, here is my code:

```
func stream(_ aStream: Stream, handle eventCode: Stream.Event) {

    if aStream === inputStream {
        switch eventCode {
        case Stream.Event.errorOccurred:
            print("input: ErrorOccurred: \(String(describing: aStream.streamError))")
        case Stream.Event.openCompleted:
            print("input: OpenCompleted")
        case Stream.Event.hasBytesAvailable:
            print("input: HasBytesAvailable")
            var index = 0 //this index is used to map the value from bytes below. For example, 0 is date
            var buffer = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: 4) //this breaks the bytes into groups of 4 bytes each
            while (inputStream?.hasBytesAvailable)!{
                if let length = inputStream?.read(&buffer, maxLength: buffer.count) {
                    if(length > 0){
                        let data = Data(bytes: buffer)
                        let UINT32 = UInt32(littleEndian: data.withUnsafeBytes { $0.pointee })
                let float =  data.withUnsafeBytes { $0.pointee } as Float
                        let int = data.withUnsafeBytes { $0.pointee } as Int
            //Do something with the values, map to an object, etc   
                        index += 1 //increase the index to know what the next 4 bytes should be mapped as
                    }
                }
            }

            break

        default:
            break
        }
    } ...
```